# Moodle as idp simplsamlphp

Tags: moodle

please help me to make moodle idp with SimpleSamlPHP

step by step configuration

makes Moodle an Identity Provider site: other application can use Moodle as a login portal

Requires SimpleSAMLphp, configured as IdP: https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp

please help me to make moodle idp with SimpleSamlPHP

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Do you have any specific question?

Comment: plugin that makes Moodle an Identity Provider site: other application can use Moodle as a login portal. Requires SimpleSAMLphp, configured as IdP: https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp

Answer (score 0):

SimpleSAMLphp can be set up as an IDP without using Moodle

I'm guessing you want to use SimpleSAMLphp to log into Moodle?

For that, I would strongly recommend using the SAML2 plugin

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2

It's easy to install and use, and the code is maintained by Catalyst, one of the top contributors to Moodle

The documentation is here

https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_saml2